# Does the whole Inode table get loaded in the main memory

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, inode

I know that the Inode table is stored on the HardDrive. 
But when we turn on the system, does the whole table gets loaded in the main memory or just a part of it. And which part?

Comment: `does the whole table gets loaded in the main memory or just a part of it.` - Only a part. `And which part?` - The one which is needed for perform user requests (that is, inodes which represent files opened by a user). Also some *caching* is performed, see that [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111893/how-long-do-dentries-stay-in-the-dcache).

Answer (score 1):

Inodes aren't loaded from disk until they are actually needed, i.e. when doing file access. Only the inodes that describe data that's currently being accessed are loaded. They'll stay in memory for a while (say, in the Linux VFS inode cache). But they're only loaded as necessary.

Comment: source or citation in code?